# WSDL - Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

in my application I am referencing a `WSDL` service by "Add Service Reference"
then a service reference is created. with this entry in `web.config`:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalOrder" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xx.xxx.com/ExternalOrder.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalOrder"
        contract="WebReference.IExternalOrder" name="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalOrder" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

at this point I am trying to call this WSDL functions, in order to get the data that I need:

```
var GetOrderDetails_answer = ServiceHelper.GetOrderDetails(creds, this.OrderId);
```

inside `ServiceHelper` class:

```
public static GetAdminOrderDetailResponse GetOrderDetails(Request creds, string orderId)
{
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       ExternalOrderClient EOC = new ExternalOrderClient();
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       var GAOD = new GetAdminOrderDetailRequest
       {
           OrderID = orderId,
           Password = creds.Password,
           SiteID = creds.SiteID,
           UserName = creds.UserName
       };

       try
       {
           return EOC.GetAdminOrderDetail(GAOD);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          /// TODO: log the error
          return null;
       }
}
```

The creation of the object `ExternalOrderClient` between "/////////////" lines
is throwing an exception:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'WebReference.IExternalOrder' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section.

I tried every solution I could find (most of them are about calling the `WSDL` from other project, but i have only 1 project)

What is the fix for that?

Comment: Are web.config and ServiceHelper class in the same project?

Comment: yes they are...

Comment: Try this: contract="IExternalOrder"

Comment: no change- same error